# How to filter using multiple conditions IN PANDAS DATAFRAME (operator & and operator | at same time)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with products in some hierarchy (`Category` then `Sub_type`).

```
Categories = ['Construção','Ferramentas']

Sub_types = ["Aerógrafos","Tintas","Proteção de Superfícies","Rolos","Lixas"]
```

A few products in the `sub_type = 'Lixas'` appears on both categories.

When I filter only by `sub_type` and group them by `category`, it will display on both categories.

```
df_destaque =df[df.sub_type.isin(["Aerógrafos","Tintas","Proteção de Superfícies","Rolos","Lixas"])]
```

[image]

I want "Lixas" to appear only on `category` == "Ferramentas", I dont want it on "Construção".

I tried to filter using `category == 'Construção'` and `sub_type == ['Aerógrafos','Proteção de Superfícies','Rolos','Tintas']` (as you can see, I didnt include "Lixas").

Then added a OR condition using operator `|` to do the same thing to the other `category`. `category == 'Ferramentas'` and `sub_type == ['Aerógrafos','Lixas']`

But as expected, it didnt work

This is what I tried:

```
df_destaque = df[
((df['category']=='Construção')&(df['sub_type']==["Aerógrafos","Tintas","Proteção de Superfícies","Rolos"]))
|
((df['category']=='Ferramentas')&(df['sub_type']==["Aerógrafos","Lixas"]))]
```

I got a `ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (4627,), (4,))`

Can somebody help me? Thanks

Comment: Use `df['sub_type'].isin(["Aerógrafos","Tintas","Proteção de Superfícies","Rolos"])`    Similarly in second row `df['sub_type'].isin(["Aerógrafos","Lixas"])`

Comment: Hi, appreciate your help. I didnt understand, how can I specify that the first row applies only to `category=Construção` and second to`category=Ferramentas`? This is the point I couldnt figure it out

Comment: You are doing correct. Just that you can not compare `df['sub_type']` with `[...] ` using `==`, this is possible only if `df['sub_type']` and `[...]` are of the same length. Also this is not what you wanted so you replace `==` with `isin`. Keep `(df['category']=='Construção')` and `(df['category']=='Ferramentas')` as it is.

Comment: Got it! It worked perfectly. Thanks. If you want to post as an official answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing correct. Just that you can not compare `df['sub_type']` with `[...]`  using `==`, this is possible only if `df['sub_type']` and `[...]` are of the same length. Also this is not what you want, what you want is to check for all the values in `df['sub_type']` if it's in `[...]` or not. `.isin` is a suitable function for that. So you replace `==` with isin. Keep `(df['category']=='Construção')` and `(df['category']=='Ferramentas')`

Use:

```
df_destaque = df[
((df['category']=='Construção')&(df['sub_type'].isin(["Aerógrafos","Tintas","Proteção de Superfícies","Rolos"])))
|
((df['category']=='Ferramentas')&(df['sub_type'].isin(["Aerógrafos","Lixas"])))]
```